# Delete cells data in excel using vba

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to delete data in excel cell starting at second cell for columns: F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M to the end of data.

My attempted code to resolve this is below but I believe there should be better answer for deleting all data to end of data in these columns:

```
   Private Sub DeleteData()
    Dim x
    Dim y
    Dim LastRow
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
    Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Master.xls", 0, True) 

    ' ## Open both workbooks first:
    Set x = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Master.xls")

    ' Now, copy what you want from x:
    xlApp.Sheets("Data").Range("K:K").Copy  
    Set y = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\SuiteOne.xls")

    ' Now, paste to y worksheet:
    y.Sheets("SuiteOneCaseFour").Range("E:E").PasteSpecial

    'AutoFit 
     y.Sheets("SuiteOneCaseFour").Range("E:E").Columns.AutoFit 

    'Clear fields
     LastRow = y.Sheets("SuiteOneCaseFour").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
     y.Sheets("SuiteOneCaseFour").Range("F2:M" & LastRow).ClearContents

     x.Save    
     x.Close
     y.Save
     y.Close

End Sub
DeleteData()
```

Comment: Why are you opening `C:\Master.xls` twice?

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = y.Sheets("SuiteOneCaseFour").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

y.Sheets("SuiteOneCaseFour").Range("F2:M" & LastRow).ClearContents
```

Comment: thanks for the reply - I'm getting error: Expected ')' at the second line.

Comment: @AzMar It worked for me using `Activesheet`. Is `y` variable set? Or did you accidentally delete the `)`?

Comment: I assumed "y" is set to workbook and wrote this line. You can change this line as per your need. Please paste your whole code.

Comment: @J.B. Y is a variable set yes and I did check the ) is still there.

Comment: @Brian, The reason is that this script will need to be executed from within selenium webdrive  - so it was suggested that I create an object. But for this propose I could remove it and make it work first?.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following **amended** code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub DeleteData()

Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook
Dim LastRow As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\Master.xls")

x.Sheets("Data").Range("K:K").Copy
Set y = Workbooks.Open("C:\SuiteOne.xls")

With y.Sheets("SuiteOneCaseFour")
    .Range("E:E").PasteSpecial
    .Range("E:E").Columns.AutoFit
    Set LastRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
    If Not LastRow Is Nothing Then
        .Range("F2:M" & LastRow.Row).ClearContents
    End If
End With

x.Save
x.Close
y.Save
y.Close

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Getting error: Expected ')' at this line:  LastRow = .Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

Comment: @AzMar Try it again.

Comment: @AzMar What version of Excel are you using? Are you on a PC? Maybe it has something to do with Selenium Webdrive (which I know nothing about)? All I can say, at this point, is that it works for me. I get no compile or run-time error.

Comment: I'm using 97-2003 (.xls)?.

Comment: I'm trying to get it working outside of selenium for now.

Comment: @AzMar Alas! Try it again.